# How to configure Standby database in oracle for read/write

Tags: oracle, database-design, standby

I have configured a physical standby database in Oracle 11gR2, and the standby database it's working fine. All the changes in the principal database are replicating to the standby database, the standby database is in read only mode. I want to configure the standby database for replicating the changes done in the standby database to the principal database, I mean i don't only need to open in read/write mode but also to apply the changes done in the physical standby to the principal. Any ideas of how to configure it? I have searched in the internet but I only find to open in a read/write test environment.

Comment: You can't do that with DataGuard. You'll need to look into alternatives (advanced replication, Golden Gate maybe).

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve? Bidirectional replication is a bit complex.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need a logical standby database, instead of a physical one. This is a little more complex. Not all data types are supported and when data is updated on both sides on the same time, there could be some problems ahead.

Comment: A logical standby can be read/write, but you can't write to the tables that are being synchronized by log apply. So doesn't match what is asked (unless I misunderstood the Q).

Answer (score 1):

The only sensible answer to this kind of requirement is Goldengate.  Goldengate can do two-way sync, but it costs $$, and you need to be careful in your design to try and avoid conflicts (e.g. updating the same row on both DBs).

My first question would, in reality, be to ask if is this actually necessary.  It's complex and error-prone.  There's usually a better way.